# Using R to transform all pages of a PDF into text, for multiple files

Tags: r, pdf, ocr

I'm using a looped 'pdf_render_page' function to create a bitmap of PDF documents that are then turned into raw text via the tesseract package. However this function works only given knowledge of file size. Does anyone know a way to take a pdf with an unknown page number total and discover the page count to then run this loop?

Comment: Your description of what `pdf_rendrer_page` does is wrong. Read the documentation.

Comment: there is an r package called tesseract which gives you access to the tesseract command-line tool which is a high-quality open source OCR program.

Comment: @Murphy'sLaw The documentation tells you how to render any specific page, not just the first one. After that its just basic iteration using a for-loop or apply-type function to iterate over files and pages within files. You'll be better served by learning to read the docs and use the basic features of R than you will be by being handed a solution to your specific problem. Believe me, I am trying to be helpful.

Comment: @Ista By default it renders the 1st page. Given I know the document size I can iterate a for loop over the document. However given I don't know the amount of pages, this is the problem I am trying to solve; not the previous two steps.

Comment: @Murphy'sLaw Thanks for clarifying the question. There are only 7 functions in the `pdftools` package. I'll bet you can guess which one tells you the number of pages.

Comment: @Ista got it. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using the pdftools package you can assign the length of pdf 'dummy.pdf' by doing:

```
pdf_length <- pdf_info("dummy.pdf")$pages
```